# Trying to return a level order traversal of a binary tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, tree, traversal

I have the following code that I have worked out on a whiteboard and according to that step through, it gives me the correct result; however, running it on the computer proves otherwise.  The code is as follows:

```
class TreeNode {
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val
        this.left = this.right = null
    }
}

const levelOrderBottom = root => {
    let visited = []
    if (!root) return visited
    let queue = [root, 's']
    let current
    let row = []

    while (queue.length > 1) {
        current = queue.shift()
        if (current === 's') {
            visited.unshift(row)
            row = []
            queue.push('s')
        } else {
            if (current.left) queue.push(current.left)
            if (current.right) queue.push(current.right)
            row.push(current.val)
        }
    }
    return visited
}

//example 1
const tree1 = new TreeNode(3)
tree1.left = new TreeNode(9)
tree1.right = new TreeNode(20)
tree1.right.left = new TreeNode(15)
tree1.right.right = new TreeNode(7)

console.log(levelOrderBottom(tree1)) //[ [15,7], [9,20], [3] ]
```

The tree and output should look like the below

```
Given binary tree [3,9,20,null,null,15,7],
    3
   / \
  9  20
    /  \
   15   7
return its bottom-up level order traversal as:
[
  [15,7],
  [9,20],
  [3]
]
```

However, I get only `[ [9,20] ,[3] ]`.  I am not able to pinpoint the flaw in my logic.  Any thoughts, as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You just didn't push the last `row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't call `visited.unshift(row)` in the end when `queue.length == 1`, despite `row` still containing results you want to add.

Answer (score 1):

You could store a level and assign to the level.

```js
class TreeNode {
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val
        this.left = null
        this.right = null
    }
}

const levelOrderBottom = root => {
    let visited = []
    if (!root) return visited
    let queue = [[root, 0]]

    while (queue.length) {
        let [current, level] = queue.shift()
        if (!visited[level]) visited[level] = []
        if (current.left) queue.push([current.left, level + 1])
        if (current.right) queue.push([current.right, level + 1])
        visited[level].push(current.val)
    }
    
    return visited.reverse()
}

//example 1
const tree1 = new TreeNode(3)
tree1.left = new TreeNode(9)
tree1.right = new TreeNode(20)
tree1.right.left = new TreeNode(15)
tree1.right.right = new TreeNode(7)

console.log(levelOrderBottom(tree1)) //[ [15,7], [9,20], [3] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need to separate into levels, you don't need to use a queue:

```
const levelOrderBottom = root => {
  let visited = []
  let row = root ? [root] : []
  while(row.length > 0) {
    visited.unshift(row.map(n => n.val))
    row = row
      .flatMap(n => [n.left, n.right])
      .filter(n => n!=null);
  }
  return visited
}
```